# Reference a Set of File Paths Using a Regular Expression

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, file-io

Can I do one read to disk with a regular expression instead of doing this three times?

```
var path = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(string.Format("~/Assets/Images/{0}.png", id)); 

if (!File.Exists(path))
{
    path = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(string.Format("~/Assets/Images/{0}.jpg", id));

    if (!File.Exists(path))
    {
        path = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(string.Format("~/Assets/Images/{0}.gif", id));
```

Comment: What's your reason for wanting to do this? Performance?

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you don't care which you hit:

```
using System.IO

string imagesPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Assets/Images");
string path = null;
foreach (var filePath in Directory.GetFiles(imagesPath, id + ".*"))
{
    switch (Path.GetExtension(filePath))
    {
       case ".png":
       case ".jpg":
       case ".gif":
           path = filePath;
           break;
    }
}
```

If `path` is not `null` you found one.

Comment: I get "Illegal characters in path" for this approach.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this (only works in .NET4 and after):

```
string folder = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Assets/Images/");
string[] extensions = { ".jpg", ".gif", ".png" };
bool exists = Directory.EnumerateFiles(folder, "*.*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
                 .Any(f => extensions.Contains(Path.GetExtension(f)));
```

Comment: That tells you if one of the files exists, but not which one. It's pretty obvious that the OP wants the path to the existing file.

Answer (score 1):

You can get a list of all the files in the directory location and use LINQ to find the path, using [`Directory.EnumerateFiles`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.enumeratefiles.aspx):

```
var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(Server.MapPath("~/Assets/Images/"));

if(files.Contains(string.Format("{0}.png", id))
{
}
```

Depending on the number of files it *may* produce better results than your solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a modification on @Oded's idea than anything else, but I'd likely do something like this:

```
var extensions = new HashSet<string>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)  
    {  ".png", ".gif", ".jpg", ".bmp" };

var firstMatchingPath = Directory.EnumerateFiles(Server.MapPath("~/Assets/Images/"))
     .Where(s => extensions.Contains(Path.GetExtension(s))
     .FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you?  Its using regex and keeping the priority of match

```
var folderPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(string.Format("~/Assets/Images"));

var regex = new Regex(string.Format("{0}[.](png|jpg|gif)", id));

var fileInfo = new DirectoryInfo(folderPath)
    .GetFiles()
    .Where(w => regex.Match(w.Name).Success)
    .OrderByDescending(o => o.Extension)
     // Taking advantage of png jpg gif is reverse alphabetical order,
     // take .OrderByDecending() out if you don't care which one gets found first
    .FirstOrDefault();

var path = fileInfo != default(FileInfo) ? fileInfo.FullName : string.Empty;
```

If I were to shrink it a little (2 statements)

```
var fileInfo = new DirectoryInfo(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(string.Format("~/Assets/Images")))
    .GetFiles()
    .Where(w => Regex.Match(w.Name, string.Format("{0}[.](png|jpg|gif)", id)).Success)
    .OrderByDescending(o => o.Extension)
    .FirstOrDefault();

var path = fileInfo != default(FileInfo) ? fileInfo.FullName : string.Empty;
```

Answer (score 0):

A lot of good answers but I went with this approach that combines a couple.

```
var path = Directory.EnumerateFiles(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Assets/Images/"), string.Format("{0}.*", id), SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly).FirstOrDefault();

switch (Path.GetExtension(path))
{
    case ".png":
    case ".jpg":
    case ".gif":
        break;
    default:
        return;
}
```